# Issue with "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

Tags: java, html, servlets, server, tomcat8

I'm trying to run a web application via tomcat 8.5 and keep getting this error after I run it. I'm able to get to the static home page but navigating from there gives me this error.
[Heres the file structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfonb.png)

This is the code for my servlet currently:

```
package controllers;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import concrete.ConcreteProject;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ConcreteProjectServlet
 */
@WebServlet(
        description = "A controller for the Concrete Project application", 
        urlPatterns = { 
                "/ConcreteProjectServlet", 
                "/getSlabHTML",
                "/cost.jsp"
        })
public class ConcreteProjectServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3649273685L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ConcreteProjectServlet() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // get the input data from the request object 
        double slabWidth = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("slabWidth"));
        double slabLength = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("slabLength"));
        double slabThickness = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("slabThickness"));
        double bagWeight = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("bagWeight"));
        //perform any conversions on the data to make it usable in our code
        //create a project object with the input data (this is one of the outputs)
        ConcreteProject cp = new ConcreteProject(slabWidth, slabLength, slabThickness, bagWeight);
        //using the project object, create the output as a string
        String projectHTML = cp.getSlabHTML();
        //store the output value somewhere that the view can get it - the request object will work here
        request.setAttribute("projectHTML",projectHTML);
        request.setAttribute("cp", cp);
        //pass control to the jsp view component
        String url = "/cost.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(url);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

And for the JSP file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Concrete Project Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Concrete Project Calculator</h1>
    
    <p>Here are the results of the project calculations:</p>
    
    SLAB DIMENSIONS HERE <br>
    
    NUMBER OF BAGS HERE <br>
    
    TOTAL COST HERE <br>
    
    <p>
        <a href="index.html"> Calculate Again </a>
    </p>
    

</body>
</html>
```

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Concrete Project Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Concrete Project Calculator</h1>
    
    <h3>Please enter the following values:</h3>
    
    <form action="getSlabHTML" method="get">
        
        <p>
            <label for="slabWidth">
                Slab Width (in feet):
            </label>
            <input type="number" name="slabWidth" value="" min="0"/>
        </p>
        
        <p>
            <label for="slabLength">
                Slab Length (in feet):
            </label>
            <input type="number" name="slabLength" value="" min="0"/>
        </p>
        
        <p>
            <label for="slabThickness">
                Slab Thickness (in inches):
            </label>
            <input type="number" name="slabThickness" value="" min="0"/>
        </p>
        
        <p>
            <label>
                Choose a Bag Weight:<br>
            </label>
            <input type="radio" id="80" name="bagWeight" value="80 lbs"/>
                <label for="80"> 80 lbs </label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="60" name="bagWeight" value="60 lbs"/>
                <label for="60"> 60 lbs </label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="50" name="bagWeight" value="50 lbs"/>
                <label for="50"> 50 lbs </label>
        </p>
        
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate" />
            <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
        </p>
        
        
    
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

And the ConcreteProject.java code:

```
**
 * 
 */
package concrete;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

/**
 * @author jordanwebster
 *
 */
public class ConcreteProject {

    private double slabWidth; //width of slab in feet
    private double slabLength; //length of slab in feet
    private double slabThickness; //thickness of slab in inches
    private double bagWeight; //weight of bag chosen in lbs
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    public ConcreteProject() {
    }

    /**
     * @param slabWidth
     * @param slabLength
     * @param slabThickness
     * @param bagWeight
     */
    public ConcreteProject(double slabWidth, double slabLength, double slabThickness, double bagWeight) {
        this.slabWidth = slabWidth;
        this.slabLength = slabLength;
        this.slabThickness = slabThickness;
        this.bagWeight = bagWeight;
    }

    /**
     * @return the slabWidth
     */
    public double getSlabWidth() {
        return slabWidth;
    }

    /**
     * @param slabWidth the slabWidth to set
     */
    public void setSlabWidth(double slabWidth) {
        this.slabWidth = slabWidth;
    }

    /**
     * @return the slabLength
     */
    public double getSlabLength() {
        return slabLength;
    }

    /**
     * @param slabLength the slabLength to set
     */
    public void setSlabLength(double slabLength) {
        this.slabLength = slabLength;
    }

    /**
     * @return the slabThickness
     */
    public double getSlabThickness() {
        return slabThickness;
    }

    /**
     * @param slabThickness the slabThickness to set
     */
    public void setSlabThickness(double slabThickness) {
        this.slabThickness = slabThickness;
    }

    /**
     * @return slab volume based on width, length, thickness
     */
    public double getSlabVolume() {
        double slabVolume;
        
        slabVolume = (this.slabWidth/3) * (this.slabLength/3)  * (this.slabThickness/36);
        
        return slabVolume;
    }

    /**
     * @return the bagWeight
     */
    public double getBagWeight() {
        return bagWeight;
    }

    /**
     * @param bagWeight the bagWeight to set
     */
    public void setBagWeight(int bagWeight) {
        this.bagWeight = bagWeight;
    }

    /**
     * @return calculate bag volume by bag weight
     */
    public double getBagVolume() {
        double bagVolume;
        
        if (this.bagWeight == 80) {
            bagVolume = 0.022;
        }
        else if (this.bagWeight == 60) {
            bagVolume = 0.0167;
        }
        else if (this.bagWeight == 50) {
            bagVolume = 0.0138;
        }
        else {
            bagVolume = 0;
        }
        
        return bagVolume;
    }

    /**
     * @param numBags the numBags to set
     */
    public double getNumBags() {
        double numBags;
        
        numBags = this.getSlabVolume()/this.getBagVolume();
        
        return numBags;
    }
    
    public double getTotalCost() {
        double totalCost;
        double costPerBag;
        
        if (this.bagWeight == 80) {
            costPerBag = 3.75;
        }
        else if (this.bagWeight == 60) {
            costPerBag = 2.83;
        }
        else if (this.bagWeight == 50) {
            costPerBag = 2.45;
        }
        else {
            costPerBag = 0;
        }
        
        totalCost = costPerBag * this.getNumBags();
        
        return totalCost; 
    }
    
    public String getSlabHTML() {
        String slabHTML = "";
        
        NumberFormat cf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        NumberFormat vf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        
        cf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2); //rounds dollar amount to 2 decimal places
        vf.setMaximumFractionDigits(4); //rounds volume to 4 decimal places
        
        slabHTML += "<h2>Concrete Calculations </h2>";
        slabHTML += "<p> Slab Width: " + vf.format(slabWidth) + " feet </p>";
        slabHTML += "<p> Slab Length: " + vf.format(slabLength) + " feet </p>";
        slabHTML += "<p> Slab Thickness: " + vf.format(slabThickness) + " inches </p>";
        slabHTML += "<p> Slab Volume: " + vf.format(this.getSlabVolume()) + " cubic yards </p>";
        slabHTML += "<p> Number of Bags Needed: " + vf.format(this.getNumBags()) + " </p>";
        slabHTML += "<p> Total cost of project using " + this.getBagWeight() + "lb bags: " + cf.format(this.getTotalCost()) + " </p>";
        
        
        return slabHTML;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!